# Android:where to store large arrays of frames before encoding?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, encode, frames, large-data

I am facing a programming problem

I am trying to encode video from camera frames that I have merged with other frames which were retrieved from other layer(like bitmap/GLsurface)

When I use 320X240 .I can make the merge in real time with fine FPS(~10),but when I try to increase the pixels size I am getting less than 6 FPS.
It is sensible as my merging function  depend on the pixels size.

**So what I  ask is, how to store that Arrays of frames for after processing (encode)?**

I don't know how to store this large arrays.

Just a quick calculation: 
If i need to store 10 frame per second
and each frame is 960X720 pixel
so i need to store for 40 second video : 40X10X960X720X(3/2-android factor)=~ 276 MB

it is to much for heap

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply record the camera input as video - 40 sec will not be a large file even at 720p resolution - and then offline you can decode, merge, and encode again. The big trick is that MediaRecorder will use hardware, so encoding will be really fast. Being compressed, the video can be written to sdcard or local file system in real time, and reading it for decoding is not an issue, too.

Comment: yes but how to decode and encode?i need FFmpeg for this?i only know how to encode in real time.do you know how to decode encode?

Comment: You can look at http://android-chirag.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/video-recording-example-in-android.html

Comment: this link use the MediaRecorder-which is impossible to decode and encode back.i have to use FFmpeg for this operations.

Comment: Why is it impossible to decode the result of MediaRecorder? I am not saying this is the only option, you can do same in native code with OpenMAX IL, or with MediaCodec, or use stagefright. You can even use ffmpeg, if you feel more comfortable with it, but the catch is to employ the hardware encoder (and building ffmpeg for Android with stagefright support is not much easier, IMHO, than the other alternatives).

Comment: how can i decode it?with the android API? i didnt find any decode/encode function with media recorder.maybe in 4.3 but i target lower OS versions

Comment: Oh, to decode I would suggest ffmpeg, also for re-encoding the mixed video. First of all, this is not a real-time limitation. Also, decoding is much lighter than encoding. Also, you don't need as much control over intermediate encoded video.